# Как почистить кэш шаринга ссылок в Telegram?

Tags: веб-программирование

Добрый день. У facebook и vk еть такие сервисы 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ https://vk.com/dev/pages.clearCache
для очистки кэша отдельных внешних страниц. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать тоже самое для Telegram?

Answer (score 5):

Ответ немного запоздалый, но думаю актуально будет еще долго

Для того что-бы обновить превью ссылки, необходимо отправить ее боту [@WebpageBot](http://telegram.me/WebpageBot).